# What's the difference between these two domains?

Tags: php, wordpress, devops, trellis, roots-sage

I'm currently learning about [Roots.io](http://roots.io)'s Trellis.

In their config they have a file called 'wordpress_sites.yml' as you can see [here](https://roots.io/trellis/docs/wordpress-sites/).

After reading the Docs, I'm still confused as to what the difference is between these:

```
wordpress_sites:
  example.com: (what is this domain used for?)
    site_hosts:
      - example.dev (why do I need this if I have the one above?)
```

Currently, my local environment seems to run off the example.dev but some plugins within my wordpress installation use 'example.com' as their path for loading resources which **subsequently breaks the plugin due to it not being a real path**.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`example.com` in that example is used only as a name. It isn't a domain name, even if it looks like one. It is used as an identifier.

`site_hosts` is a *list* of host names that the site will be available on. You would generally want to have `example.com` as one of them. This lets you provide the same site on multiple hostnames.

Normally you wouldn't want to make it available on multiple *public-facing* host names (because having duplicate sites is generally considered A Bad Idea), but it lets you have one configuration file used by both your live site and your internal-only development, test and integration sites.

Comment: If that's the case then how do I stop a WordPress plugin trying to load it's resources from the identifier domain and make it load from the defined site_host domain?